# Significance test for treatment when baseline of control and test groups are different

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ab-test, pre-post-comparison, baseline

I have two groups of different sizes (control and test) and I want to measure the impacte of a certain treatment on the test group. Unfortunately, the control group has a different baseline compared to the test group, before the treatment was put in effect. Despite this difference in baseline, I want to be able to determine if the treatment caused a significant change in the test group.

To make it more concrete: let's say I want to measure the impact on order value as a result of treatment X. Treatment X is only applied to customers in the test group. Existing customers are randomly assigned either control (15%) or test group (85%), and the same is done for new customers. Example data might look like this:

**Before period** (28 days before start of test period)

| Group | Number of orders | Average order value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Control | 1500 | 50 |
| Test | 8000 | 48 |

**Test period** (starting treatment X up until today)

| Group | Number of orders | Average order value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Control | 2000 | 52 |
| Test | 11000 | 52 |

In the before period, the average order value in the test group is significantly lower, as determined by a t-test.

Given this scenario, what would be an applicable method and significance test to determine if treatment X caused a significant higher average order value in the test group?

#### What I have tried so far

---

- [perform a t-test to test if the mean improvement percentages is different in the test group and the control group](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45867/statistical-significance-between-two-percentage-change?rq=1) → This doesn't really work for my scenario, since I did not measure improvement for every memnber in every group. Some customers placed orders in both before and after period, while some customers only place and order in either before or after period
- [perform a logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90029/test-of-significance-for-comparing-change-between-two-groups?rq=1) → I don't have a categorical variable, but rather a normally distributed real-valued variable
- [segmented intervention analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43448/what-test-should-i-use-to-determine-if-a-policy-change-had-a-statistically-signi?rq=1) → This feels like a less favorable approach to me, given I have a control and test group which should allow me to 'correct' for any seasonality or other factors